# Fatal error on R (3.6.1) with RQDA library

Tags: r, crash, rstudio, rqda

R 3.6.1 Crashes when I load RQDA library on macOS 10.14.5.
I get the following Traceback :

> library(RQDA)
>   Loading required package: RSQLite
>   Loading required package: gWidgetsRGtk2
>   Loading required package: RGtk2
>   Loading required package: gWidgets
>   Loading required package: cairoDevice
>   Loading required package: DBI

Use 'RQDA()' to start the programme.

*** caught segfault ***
address 0x0, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .RGtkCall("S_gtk_tree_store_set_value", object, iter, column,     value, PACKAGE = "RGtk2")
 2: method(obj, ...)
 3: store$SetValue(iter$iter, column = 0, items[j, 1])
 4: `.leftBracket<-`(`*tmp*`, x@toolkit, i, j, ..., value = value)
 5: `.leftBracket<-`(`*tmp*`, x@toolkit, i, j, ..., value = value)
 6: `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , value = list(items = c("blue", "white", "aliceblue",

Appreciate any help

ACSF

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  The gtree widget seems to be the culprit.  Can you run the tests for gwidgets?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem, too, and solved it as follows:

1. Install MacPorts (or some equivalent package/port manager). You may need to install Apple's standard command line developer tools as part of this.
2. Install pkgconfig and GTK2 via your package/port manager
3. Start R
4. Install RGtk2 and cairoDevice from source
5. Install other components of RQDA as you normally would.

Tested in December 2019 on a clean install of R 3.6.2 on MacOS 10.14.6, using MacPorts 2.6.2